# Construct a probability density function $w(x)$ given another probability density function $f(x)$ with specified moments

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a probability density function $f$

and $\int_a^bf(x)dx>0$

given $a,b \in R$ and $b>a$ , $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Can we construct a probability density function $w(x)$ such that:

let $g(x)=f(x)-w(x)$

1. $g(x)$ is differentiable everywhere
2. $u=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xw(x)dx$
3. $\sigma=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2w(x)dx$
4. $g(a)=g(b)=0$
5. $g(x)$ is non trivial, that is $\mu(\{x \in R : |g(x) |>0\}) \neq 0$

Comment: @kimchilover typo

Comment: It seems in this case that $f$ is a probability density function, rather than being a probability distribution function $f(x) = P(X \le x)$ for some random variable $X$. Is that so?

Comment: @LostStatistician18 that's right

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is Riemann Integrable then $w(x)$ can be constructed as follows :

$$n,j,k \in N, a_1=a,a_{n+1}=b,\delta,\epsilon >0 $$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}(a_{j+1}-a_j)=b-a$$

$s_{j,k}(x)=-{\frac {\epsilon}{k(x^2-a_j^2)}}$

$t_{j,k}(x)=-{\frac {\epsilon}{k(a_{j+1}^2-x^2)}}$

$$\phi_{j,k}(x) =e^{s_{j,k}(x)+t_{j,k}(x)} , \text{if $a_j< x< a_{j+1}$ }$$

$$\phi_{j,k}(x) =0  , \text{if $x$ $\notin (a_j,a_{j+1})$}$$

$$p_j=\min_{x \in [a_j,a_{j+1})} f(x)$$

because $f$ is Riemann integrable there is a partitioning such that for $x \in [a_j,a_{j+1}]$,
 $f(x)-p_j \le \delta$ and there is some $j=m$ , such that $p_m(x) \neq 0$ since $\int_a^bf(x)dx>0$

let $$g(x)= A\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,1}+ B\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,2}(x)+ C\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,3}(x)+D\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,4}(x)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,k}(x) <\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,k+1}(x) \text{for $x \neq a_j$ }$$

let $v_k=\int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j\phi_{j,k}(x)dx$

let $u_k=\int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}xp_j\phi_{j,k}(x)dx$

let $\sigma_k=\int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}x^2p_j\phi_{j,k}(x)dx$

$$v_k>0, \sigma_k> 0$$

We have an undetermined system of equations ( has infinte number of non trivial solutions):

$$v_1A+v_2B+v_3C+v_4D=0$$

$$u_1A+u_2B+u_3C+u_4D=0$$

$$\sigma_1A+\sigma_2B+\sigma_3C+\sigma_4D=0$$

We  take any of these non trivial solutions with $|A|+|B|+|C|+|D| < 1$, This is possible for undetermined system of linear equations 
there is always an independent variable, and any relationship between variables is continuous.

Note $$f(x)- g(x) \ge 0$$

writing $$w_{\epsilon}(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$

$$w(x) \text{ can represent a probability density function with same mean and variance as $f(x)$ }$$

$$\text{Remark:if $f \in L^2$ , then by Dominated Convergence Theorem} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_a^b\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} f(x)\phi_{j,k}(x)dx =\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}\int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}} p_jf(x)dx $$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_a^b(f^2(x)-\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} f(x)\phi_{j,k})dx =\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}\int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}}(f^2(x)-p_jf(x))dx \le \sum_{j=1}^{j=n}\int_{a_j}^{a_{j+1}} \delta f(x)dx=\delta \int_a^b f(x)dx$$